# Reduce kafka offset by one message size

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, kafka-consumer-api

I have a kafka cluster setup. Most of the times the consumer runs unattended. It reads the messages and invokes an external API. But if the external API is down(which happens rarely), I need to retry the message for a fixed time. If retry fails, I need to stop the consumer  and start again after a fixed time.

The problem is I need to handle the last read message from topic. Is there a way i can reset the zookeeper offset to the one before reading the message?(That is reduce the offset by one message). So next time i start the consumer, i can read the message again.

This can be done by using low level consumer. But is there a way to do that with High level consumer?

I am using Java based consumer client.

Comment: If applicable, a very simple solution is to push back the message in the topic when stopping. You can even have a dedicated topic, and consume from both.

Answer (score 2):

You need to commit offsets to zookeeper.
Look to the next consumer configs:
http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#consumerconfigs

> **auto.commit.enable**: If true, periodically commit to ZooKeeper the
>   offset of messages already fetched by the consumer. This committed
>   offset will be used when the process fails as the position from which
>   the new consumer will begin.
>
> **auto.commit.interval.ms**:   The frequency in
>   ms that the consumer offsets are committed to zookeeper.

If you want to commit offset after each message you need:

```
auto.commit.enable=false
```

And commit offsets after successful operation:

```
consumer.commitOffsets(true)
```

It's not recommended to do it after each message or to have small commit interval because it increases read/write load on zookeeper.

Also you can look to the new offset management(offsets are stored in brokers instead of zookeper):

http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html

> Kafka provides the option to store all the offsets for a given
>   consumer group in a designated broker (for that group) called the
>   offset manager. i.e., any consumer instance in that consumer group
>   should send its offset commits and fetches to that offset manager
>   (broker)

Comment: Thanks. But is the new consumer released? The examples in Kafka site is still using 0.8.0 . Also i read that 0.9 will be the next major release. The documentation mentions 0.8.2 though..